Koin: inject object returned by suspend function
I have object which created by suspend function like:
suspend fun someSuspendFunction(): MyPreciousObject
And I need to provide it for later injection using koin, like:
val myModule = module {
       single<MyPreciousObject> {
         //can call suspend function only from a coroutine or another suspend function
         someSuspendFunction() 
    }
}

Any ideas how to resolve this kind of situation? And please bear in mind that I can't change someSuspendFunction()
P.S. I'm using Kotlin JS/WASM environment, so runBlocking doesn't exist

I suppose the best you can get is to use runBlocking. Koin should be fine with a blocking object producer and performance doesn't matter in this case as this is just initialization.

@broot unfortunately runBlocking doesn't exist in KotlinJS (which is my case)

One DI pattern I have often used is a holder object that you can inject anywhere:
class MyPreciousObjectHolder
{
   var value: MyPreciousObject? = null
}

Then proceed as follows:

Make the holder object injectable
Resolve it in some kind of filter object that runs before your module and which can run a suspend operation to set the value
Your module then receives a holder with a populated value

I am no expert on koin though, so I cannot say for sure that this will work in that tech stack.
